# Implementation from MATLAB to Python without iterations

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, iteration

Suppose you have the following code in MATLAB:

```
    [xi yi imv] = find(imagee+0.1);
    imv = imv - 0.1;
    wv = abs(imv*ones(1,length(imv)) - ones(length(imv),1)*imv');
```

And you want to implement this code in Python. Imagee is a predefined, synthetic image represented by a 10x10 array with values 0,1,2. What would be the most efficient method of accomplishing this? I know you could iteratively walk through the entire matrix and modify values as you go, but I'm sure python has a faster method than that.

EDIT: to clarify on imagee:(I have translated this to python already)

```
    C= np.zeros((L,L), int)
    C[:L/2,:L/2]=1
    C[L/2:L,:L/2]=2
```

Comment: I don't think you have to devectorize anything here. Just use `numpy` and write the vectorized python equivalent. I don't think there's anything in there that cannot be translated 1 to 1 into operations on whole `numpy` arrays.

Comment: "Imagee is a predefined, synthetic image represented by a 10x10 array with values 0,1,2. " <- To improve the question you could instead define `imagee` with a line or two of runnable Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the necessary adjustment.In matlab, Imagee is the same dimensions as the array defined in my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're already using `numpy`, which is a step in the right direction.  Now, let's go through each statement one at a time and get the `numpy` equivalent of what you're after.  It says that your matrix is `10 x 10`, and so I'm going to assume that `L = 10`.  Here's what we'll start with (in IPython):

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: L = 10

In [4]: C= np.zeros((L,L), int)

In [5]: C[:L/2,:L/2]=1

In [6]: C[L/2:L,:L/2]=2

In [7]: C
Out[7]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Now, let's go through each line one at a time.

---

```
[xi yi imv] = find(imagee+0.1);
```

`imv` basically gives you a vector of all values in `imagee+0.1` that are non-zero.  However, what you need to keep in mind is that MATLAB will return these values **in column-major** order whereas `numpy` will do the same operation in **row-major** order.  If you want to replicate the same behaviour in Python, you'll need to **transpose** the matrix first.  As such, I'll create a new matrix which transposes `imagee` and adds 0.1 to every entry for convenience. However, I'm a bit confused because if `imagee` already consists of `0,1,2`, if you add every value in this matrix by 0.1, `imv` will return **all** values in `imagee+0.1`.... and that seems pointless to me.  Nevertheless, you can use [`numpy.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to give you the locations of the non-zero elements.  Once you find these non-zero elements, you can simply index into the transpose of `C` added with `0.1` to get the values you want.  `numpy.nonzero` will return a tuple of two elements where the first element is an array that tells you the row locations of those values that were non-zero in `C+0.1` and the second element is an array that tells you the column locations that were non-zero in `C+0.1`:

```
In [9]: CT = C.T + 0.1

In [10]: ind = CT.nonzero()

In [11]: imv = CT[ind[0], ind[1]]

In [12]: imv
Out[12]:
array([ 1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  1.1,
    1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  1.1,  1.1,
    1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,
    1.1,  1.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  1.1,
    1.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,
    0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,
    0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,
    0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,
    0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,
    0.1])
```

If you did the same operation in MATLAB, you'll notice that `imv` in both Python and MATLAB give the same order of values.

---

```
imv = imv - 0.1;
```

That's easy:

```
In [22]: imv = imv - 0.1

In [23]: imv
Out[23]:
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

---

```
wv = abs(imv*ones(1,length(imv)) - ones(length(imv),1)*imv');
```

The first part of this statement (inside the `abs` call) is performing the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors.  In MATLAB, `imv` would be `N x 1`, and you are multiplying this with a `1 x N` vector of ones.  You can use [`numpy.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) to help you do this outer product step.  Take note that for 1D arrays, `numpy` does not distinguish between row vectors and column vectors and so multiplying a vector with the transpose of another unfortunately won't give you what you expect. However, if you want this behaviour, you must explicitly define a 2D matrix that has a singleton dimension of 1 (either the rows or the columns), but let's put that aside for this post.

The second part of this statement also performs an outer product but on the transposed version of the first part of the statement.

Therefore:

```
In [24]: ones_vector = np.ones(len(imv))

In [25]: wv = np.abs(np.outer(imv, ones_vector) - np.outer(ones_vector, imv))

In [26]: wv
Out[26]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   ...,
   [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The first part of the code declares a vector of ones for convenience.  After that, we calculate what you desire.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your step-by-step walkthrough really helped me understand more about converting between matlab matrices and python numpy arrays.

Comment: One more question I discovered after implementation: in np.outer(imv,0),  documentation states that the second parameter is the second vector. Why is this zero? Why is it not a vector full of ones?

Comment: EDIT: I just now remembered we initialized 0 as our vector of ones. It must be too early for me to code. :)

Comment: @BrandonGinley - lol sorry.  I probably should choose my variables more carefully.  I've changed `O` to `ones_vector`.  Thanks for checking!

Comment: @BrandonGinley - Made a small edit to my post. I forgot that MATLAB did things in column-major.... but it actually doesn't change what the final answer is.  However, to be 100% correct I did a small change at the beginning of the code followed by some explanations.  Good luck!