# Implementation from MATLAB to Python using numpy and cv2

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, numpy

I am in the process of attempting to implement a script in MATLAB over to Python. I have the following:

```
% I = im2double(imread('images\image.tif'));
% IC(:,:,1) = imresize(squeeze(I(:,:,1)),[N1 N2]);
% IC(:,:,2) = imresize(squeeze(I(:,:,2)),[N1 N2]);
% IC(:,:,3) = imresize(squeeze(I(:,:,3)),[N1 N2]);

and

[xi yi imv1] = find(squeeze(imagee(:,:,1))+0.1);
imv1 = imv1 - 0.1;
wd1 = (imv1*ones(1,length(imv1)) - ones(length(imv1),1)*imv1').^2;
```

I understand I can load the image with open cv, i.e.

```
I= cv2.imread('image',1)
```

And that I can use np.nonzero for MATLAB find,

```
index=(imagee+0.1).nonzero()
```

np.outer for the wd1 calculation:

```
timv1=np.transpose(imv1)
wd1 = np.abs(np.outer(imv1,holder1) - np.outer(holder1,timv1))
```

as well as np.squeeze for MATLAB's squeeze function.
However, how can i write these functions in a compact form to produce maximum efficiency and speed when the Python script is finalized?

Comment: The `squeeze` call in the `find` command for MATLAB is redundant.  There's no need to squeeze out any of those singleton dimensions because there are none.  The way the MATLAB code is written in comparison to the Python code is as compact as you can get it... if you refer to our previous question and answer together: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549296/implementation-from-matlab-to-python-without-iterations - Instead, I will ask you this.  Why do you feel the need to make this in compact form for "maximum efficiency"?  How do you gauge that this code isn't efficient?

Comment: My understanding is that python is much faster when written in certain forms. The purpose of the movement from matlab to python is to reduce calculation times when the input matrices become very large. I am posing this question because it is difficult to search documentation for the methods which are the fastest, and while I can construct an equivalent method in Python, I am unsure if it is the fastest method.

Comment: That's a little too broad because there are many ways that you could write the above statement and each of them have varying times.  You won't get one implementation that everyone will agree that it's absolutely the fastest.